# WCF Data Service Versioning with EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, versioning, wcf-data-services

I have multiple clients and a central server.

The server is using a WCF data service to allow clients to update data. An EF Model interfaces the server Data services. Clients use the below code.

```
svr.AddToTable(NewData)
svr.SaveChanges()
```

I need to let the server DB add columns to tables and allow clients to continue to work with the data. If the EF model is not updated this is possible.

I want to go a step further and be able to upgrade the WCF data service to refer to new columns (by updating the EF Model) so that clients who are upgraded can insert data to the new columns, while old clients can still continue to update atleast the old columns.

Hence I'm thinking there will be WCF Services versioned each linked to a different version of the EF Model. Is this possible? If so how do I do this versioning?

Comment: "I need to let the server DB add columns to tables and allow clients to continue to work with the data. If the EF model is not updated this is possible." False premise. Adding columns will not break your model, even if it's not updated.

Answer (score 0):

A response to this post can be found here :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/0120e14f-b2de-4ea5-a66d-3d943edd9582

> If you set the [IgnoreMissingProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoremissingproperties.aspx) property on the DataServiceContext to true, the client will ignore any extra properties included in an entry in the feed returned from the data service (...)